# error while trying to add new value for JPA table

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, eclipselink, derby

Im using JPa API's and its work well ,I have tried to add new member/column to the class(table) and when I was tried to add data for it works fine but in the commit part I get dump with the following error

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'DOUBLE1' is not a column in table or VTI 'TEST.PERSON'.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, DOUBLE1, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, NONSENSEFIELD) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [5 parameters bound]

But in the table person I have added the member double1 as follows

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private double double1;

....

    public double getDouble1() {

        return double1;
    }

    public void setDouble1(double double1) {

        this.double1 = double1;
    }
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is obviously no column DOUBLE1 in the database table VTI 'TEST.PERSON'. Adding a new field to a JPA entity does not automatically make it appear in the database as well.

Comment: I didnt create the tables I just create the class with the fields that I need

Comment: You have probably configured EclipseLink to automatically create tables for you. That means however, that the table is automatically created, but not automatically modified (if already present and changes are made to the entity). I have absolutely no idea which database you are using, but I am pretty sure that it comes with a documentation telling you how to add columns to an existing table. Alternatively, you can drop the existing table (and all the data) and let EcliplseLink create a new table for you with the correct columns.

Comment: I Using Derby Db ,How should I drop the existing table ? Thanks!

Comment: You can also use "create-or-extend-tables" described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/DesignDocs/368365

Comment: @Chris: Good point. I didn't know that extend functionality had been added to the latest version of EclipseLink.

Comment: Chris Thanks this solve the problem ,Can you please change the comment to answer

Comment: I have a somewhat same problem so help me if you can https://stackoverflow.com/q/49382487/4356983

Comment: @YogeshDoke I checked your question and your lack of ability to read and understand a very obvious error message was worth a downvote from me as well.