# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ITEM_QTY' cannot accept a NULL value

Tags: java, maven, jpa, eclipselink, derby

I'm using JPA API's and it works well,  I have tried to add new member/column to the class and when I tried to add data into it using form,  it shows "TRANSACTION ABORTED" error.

```
"javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'ITEM_QTY'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO ITEM (B_ID, DESCRIPTION, ITEM_NAME, ITEM_PRICE, MANUFACTURER, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [6 parameters bound]"
```

and this error is shown in glassfish logs

These are my generated entities 
Item_.java

```
package Entities;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.5.2.v20140319-rNA", date="2018-03-20T16:09:40")
@StaticMetamodel(Item.class)
public class Item_ { 

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, Long> item_id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, Long> b_id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, Double> item_price;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, String> description;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, String> item_name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Item, String> manufacturer;

}
```

and Scarf.java

```
package Entities;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.SingularAttribute;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.StaticMetamodel;

@Generated(value="EclipseLink-2.5.2.v20140319-rNA", date="2018-03-20T16:09:40")
@StaticMetamodel(Scarf.class)
public class Scarf_ extends Item_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Scarf, Long> t_id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Scarf, Double> final_price;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Scarf, Double> discount;

}
```

EJB's

Item.java

```
/*

package Entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

/**
 * Creates Item Superclass Object
 * @author josh
 */
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Item  implements Serializable {

    // Attributes
        public static final String ITEM = "Item.findAllItems";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long item_id;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public Long b_id;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public String manufacturer;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public String item_name;
    @Size(max = 2000)
    @Column(length = 2000)
    public String description;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public double item_price;

    /**
     * Empty Constructor
     */
    public Item() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with Data
     * @param b_id
     * @param item_name
     * @param manufacturer
     * @param description
     * @param item_price
     */
    public Item(long b_id ,String item_name, String manufacturer, String description, double item_price) 
    {
        this.b_id = b_id;
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.description = description;
        this.item_price = item_price;

    }

    /**
     * Get and Set Methods
     * @return 
     */    
    public Long getId() {
        return item_id;
    }

    public void setId(Long i) {
        this.item_id = i;
    }

    public Long getB_id() {
        return b_id;
    }

    public void setB_id(Long i) {
        this.b_id = i;
    }

    public String getItem_name() {
        return item_name;
    }

    public void setItem_name(String i) {
        this.item_name = i;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String m) {
        this.manufacturer = m;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String d) {
        this.description = d;
    }

    public double getItem_price() {
        return item_price;
    }

    public void setItem_price(double i) {
        this.item_price = i;
    }

    /**
     * Search Methods
     */  
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (item_id != null ? item_id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Item)) {
            return false;
        }
        Item other = (Item) o;
        if ((this.item_id == null && other.item_id != null) || (this.item_id != null && !this.item_id.equals(other.item_id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * ToString Override Method
     * */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format (
       "%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n",
            "Barcode: ",Long.toString(b_id),
            "Item Name: ",this.item_name,
            "Manufacturer: ",this.manufacturer, 
            "Item Price: ",Double.toString(item_price),
            "Category: ",this.description
        );
    } 
}
```

Scarf.java

```
/*

package Entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

/**
 * Creates Scarf Subclass Object
 *
 */
@Entity
public class Scarf extends Item implements Serializable 
{

    // Attributes
    public static final String SCARFS = "Scarf.findAllScarfs";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    public long t_id;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public double discount;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    public double final_price;


    /**
     * Empty Constructor
     */
    public Scarf() {
    }

    /**
     * Constructor with Data
     * @param b_id
     * @param item_name
     * @param manufacturer
     * @param description
     * @param item_price
     * @param t_id
     * @param discount
     * @param final_price

     */
    public Scarf(long b_id, String item_name, String manufacturer, String description, double item_price, double discount, double final_price) 
    {
        super(b_id, item_name, manufacturer, description, item_price);
        this.t_id = t_id;
        this.discount = discount;
        this.final_price = final_price;
    }

    /**
     * Get and Set Methods
     *
     * @return
     */

     public Long getT_id() {
        return t_id;
    }

    public void setT_id(Long i) {
        this.t_id = i;
    }

    public double getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }

    public void setDiscount(double i) {
        this.discount = i;
    }

    public double getFinal_price() {
        return final_price;
    }

    public void setFinal_price(double i) {
        this.final_price = i;
    }

    /**
     * ToString Override Method
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n%s%s\n",
                "Item ID: ", Long.toString(this.item_id),
                "Barcode: ", Long.toString(this.b_id),
                "Item Name: ", this.item_name,
                "Manufacturer: ", this.manufacturer,
                "Description: ", this.description,
                "Item Price: ", Double.toString(item_price),
                "Tag ID: ", Long.toString(this.t_id),
                "Discount: ", Double.toString(discount),
                "Final Price: ", Double.toString(final_price)

        );
    }

}
```

Create.xhtml

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
                <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <!--Create panel-->
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Barcode" for="b_id" />
                    <h:inputText id="b_id" value="#{scarfController.selected.b_id}" title="Barcode" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Item Name" for="item_name" />
                    <h:inputText id="item_name" value="#{scarfController.selected.item_name}" title="Item Name" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Manufacturer" for="manufacturer" />
                    <h:inputText id="manufacturer" value="#{scarfController.selected.manufacturer}" title="Manufacturer" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Category" for="description" />
                    <h:inputText id="description" value="#{scarfController.selected.description}" title="Description" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Price" for="item_price" />
                    <h:inputText id="item_price" value="#{scarfController.selected.item_price}" title="Price" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Tag Barcode" for="t_id" />
                    <h:inputText id="t_id" value="#{scarfController.selected.t_id}" title="Tag Barcode" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Discount" for="discount" />
                    <h:inputText id="discount" value="#{scarfController.selected.discount}" title="Discount" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>
                    <h:outputLabel value="Final Price" for="final_price" />
                    <h:inputText id="final_price" value="#{scarfController.selected.final_price}" title="Final Price" required="false" requiredMessage="#{bundle.RequiredMessage}"/>

                </h:panelGrid>
                 <br/> 
                <h:commandLink action="#{scarfController.persistScarf}" value="#{bundle.SaveLink}" />
                 <br /> 
             <a href="/home/" >Cancel</a>
            <br />

            </h:form>
```

updates logs after adding property

```
Finer:   client acquired: 1783508080
Finer:   TX binding to tx mgr, status=STATUS_ACTIVE
Finer:   acquire unit of work: 2032803813
Finer:   TX afterCompletion callback, status=ROLLEDBACK
Finer:   release unit of work
Finer:   client released
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ScarfProducer, method: public void Beans.utility.Producer.create(java.lang.Object)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233.create(Unknown Source)
    at Beans.__EJB31_Generated__ScarfProducer__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
    at Beans.ScarfController.persistScarf(ScarfController.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

[image]

Comment: The error mentions Column 'ITEM_QTY' is null, which isn't mentioned anywhere in your code or mapping description. If you haven't mapped it, JPA can't put a value in it.

Comment: in this project I am reusing code I did  modification in code and added few attributes to the class, I also did all changes to reflect the modification, ITEM_QTY is an attribute of the old class that I removed and added my own  attributes I also dropped database and created new but same error, and  I am using EclipseLink as persistence provider so please help to solve this issue

Comment: by 'dropped database and created new' what do you mean exactly? If you get the same error, you created the same table with the same ITEM_QTY field. What ever you are using to create the database and tables needs to take into account your new model and mappings.

Comment: We are using eclipse persistent API for mapping classes into database, if you seen above code we have changed our classes according to our need, and the problem occurred and  the changed class not mapped in database, every time we clean build the project it created database with old mapping, so I think the problem is in persistent unit

Comment: 'it created database'. What is 'it'?  Nothing you've shown would add an ITEM_QTY field, and you haven't shown properties or persistence.xml that would show JPA is set to create the tables. Are you using scripts for instance that still have the old project's ITEM_QTY field in it?

Comment: here is the link to my project on github https://github.com/YogeshDoke/ESL-project/tree/master

Comment: Going through your entire project is a bit more than I can do, and it doesn't show anything anyway as there is nothing in there that I saw mentioning ITEM_QTY. You need to search your projects and ensure that where ever you are running it, there isn't some old class file getting picked up and loaded before your newer versions. Turn on EclipseLink logging to ALL or FINEST for a clue, as it will show the DDL statements and where it loads the persistence unit from, which will help track down the problem.

Comment: you checked in a war file, shouldn't you be rebuilding that from your classes?  Check that it doesn't have old versions in there from before your changes.

Comment: I also checked for ITEM_QTY multiple times, I also checked in a war file and is generated from new classes

Comment: Did you turn on Logging?  It will show you where the field is getting picked up from.

Comment: have look at this problem stackoverflow.com/q/48429456/4356983

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't rebuild/redeploy your jar file. I can see that the last time it has been built is `Dec 31 17:46:18 AEST 2015`. In your .war file there is a file inside `HatAndScarf\META-INF\maven\josh\Assignment2` which exposes this information:

```
#Generated by Maven
#Thu Dec 31 17:46:18 AEST 2015
version=1.0
groupId=josh
artifactId=Assignment2
```

I think if you try to build it via maven and then redeploy it the problem should go away.

Comment: new jar not generated, what I have to do

Comment: I can see it's generated under your "target" folder, am I missing something? Just deploy it to your tomcat (or another application server).

Comment: I am using glassfish, I deployed the same project to glassfish but the same problem

Comment: Could you please upload the new jar on github?

Comment: yes I uploaded new war here is link https://github.com/YogeshDoke/ESL-project/tree/yd

Comment: also uploaded new files from HatAndScarf\META-INF\maven\

Comment: link to new jar https://github.com/YogeshDoke/ESL-project/blob/yd/javaee-endorsed-api-7.0.jar

Comment: hey if you don't mind can we solve this problem using TeamViewer

Comment: Sorry, I have to go soon. I can see that the jar is new this time and that there is no ITEM_QTY in it. It means that you have some other deployments on glassfish that has this field. I would suggest you to remove your old .wars one by one from glassfish and see whether it helps. Make sure you remove deployments from glassfish in a correct way (I think there should be tons of articles over the internet of how to do it). If this doesn't help - try to download new glassfish installation and deploy your new war there (just to be sure.. I assume there might be a deployment cache on glassfish)

Comment: I removed old glassfish and download new but still issue not resolved same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167514/discussion-between-yogesh-doke-and-danylo-zatorsky).

Answer (score 0):

Alter your database table to drop not null constraint on ITEM_QTY column.